# Average tip amount per person

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im doing Jonas Schmedtmann's JavaScript course on Udemy. Im stuck in challenge one, a tip calculator where two persons will be compared on who paid the most average five. There are 4 and 5 bills to respective person, they use different tipping rules depending on the amount. Everything seems fine when i inspect the code but i dont get the result to add up. If you read all the Tips from each array they look right, but when working with it calculating an average it turns out wrong.

`marksAvgTips` should be 38.53 and `johnsAvgTips` should be 18.08.

Can you spot my errors? Thank you!

```
var JohnsResturantVisits = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calcTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] <= 200) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .15;
            } else {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .1;
            }
        }
    },
    tips: [],
    calcPaid: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            this.fullAmountPaid[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    },
    fullAmountPaid: []
}

JohnsResturantVisits.calcTip();
JohnsResturantVisits.calcPaid();

console.log(JohnsResturantVisits.tips);
console.log(JohnsResturantVisits.fullAmountPaid);

var MarksResturantVisits = {
    bills: [77, 475, 110, 45],
    calcTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] <= 300) {
                // console.log(this.bills[i] * 0.15);
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .1;
            } else {
                // console.log(this.bills[i] * 0.1);
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .25;
            }
        }
    },
    tips: [],
    calcPaid: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            this.fullAmountPaid[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    },
    fullAmountPaid: []
}

MarksResturantVisits.calcTip();
MarksResturantVisits.calcPaid();

console.log(MarksResturantVisits.tips);
console.log(MarksResturantVisits.fullAmountPaid);

var totalTips = 0;
var avgTips = 0;

function averageTips(who) {
    for (var i = 0; i < who.tips.length; i++) {
        totalTips += who.tips[i];
    }
    avgTips = (totalTips / who.tips.length);
    console.log(totalTips);
}

averageTips(MarksResturantVisits);
var marksAvgTips = avgTips;
console.log(marksAvgTips);
averageTips(JohnsResturantVisits);
var johnsAvgTips = avgTips;
console.log(johnsAvgTips);

if (marksAvgTips > johnsAvgTips) {
    console.log('Mark\'s family paid the higher average tip. They paid: ' +
        marksAvgTips + ' dollars.')
} if (johnsAvgTips > marksAvgTips) {
    console.log('John\'s family paid the higher average tip. They paid: ' +
        johnsAvgTips + ' dollars.')
} else {
    console.log('They paid the same amount of tips..')
}
```

Comment: marksAvgTips should be 38.53 and johnsAvgTips should be 18.08.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a global variables and not resetting them when you calculate the average. This means you end up with a bigger value than you should for the second tip calculation.

I've moved the variables into the function for calculating the tip, so they are always reset.

If you need to have the variables be global, reset their values to 0 at the top of `averageTips`.

Also your final if/else block was missing an else.

```js
var JohnsResturantVisits = {
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calcTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 50) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] >= 50 && this.bills[i] <= 200) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .15;
            } else {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .1;
            }
        }
    },
    tips: [],
    calcPaid: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            this.fullAmountPaid[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    },
    fullAmountPaid: []
}

JohnsResturantVisits.calcTip();
JohnsResturantVisits.calcPaid();

console.log(JohnsResturantVisits.tips);
console.log(JohnsResturantVisits.fullAmountPaid);

var MarksResturantVisits = {
    bills: [77, 475, 110, 45],
    calcTip: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            if (this.bills[i] < 100) {
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .2;
            } else if (this.bills[i] >= 100 && this.bills[i] <= 300) {
                // console.log(this.bills[i] * 0.15);
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .1;
            } else {
                // console.log(this.bills[i] * 0.1);
                this.tips[i] = this.bills[i] * .25;
            }
        }
    },
    tips: [],
    calcPaid: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            this.fullAmountPaid[i] = this.bills[i] + this.tips[i];
        }
    },
    fullAmountPaid: []
}

MarksResturantVisits.calcTip();
MarksResturantVisits.calcPaid();

console.log(MarksResturantVisits.tips);
console.log(MarksResturantVisits.fullAmountPaid);

function averageTips(who) {
    let totalTips = 0;
    let avgTips = 0;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < who.tips.length; i++) {
        totalTips += who.tips[i];
    }
    avgTips = (totalTips / who.tips.length);
    console.log(totalTips);
    return avgTips;
}

var marksAvgTips = averageTips(MarksResturantVisits);
console.log('mark', marksAvgTips.toFixed(2));
var johnsAvgTips = averageTips(JohnsResturantVisits);
console.log('john', johnsAvgTips.toFixed(2));

if (marksAvgTips > johnsAvgTips) {
    console.log('Mark\'s family paid the higher average tip. They paid: ' +
        marksAvgTips + ' dollars.')
} else if (johnsAvgTips > marksAvgTips) {
    console.log('John\'s family paid the higher average tip. They paid: ' +
        johnsAvgTips + ' dollars.')
} else {
    console.log('They paid the same amount of tips..')
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Silly little irritating thing :), I was on the right track atleast! Love this place!!